# Background and footer get distored in phonegap when keyboard opens

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I am facing screen issues in phonegap.I have a back button on the bottom of the page but when i open keyboard it goes above the keyboard and backround image get shorter.How can i set it.My HTML Code is:

```
<body >


 <div  class="wrapper" style="background-image: url('img/1.jpg');">
    <div  class="container">

            <div  style=" width: 100%;height:45%;">
                <img  src="img/logo.png" style="width: 60%;height: 95%;"/>
            </div>  
            <form class="form" id="myForm" method="GET" onSubmit="" style="margin-top: 13%">
            <input type="text" id="email" class="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
            <input type="password" id="pass" class="pass" name="password" placeholder="Pass" style="float: left;">
            <input type="password" id="pass2" class="again" placeholder="Again" style="float: right;">
            <input type="text" id="phone_no" class="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Mobile Number">
            <button type="submit" class="continue" onclick="sign_up_pass();transit()" >Continue</button>
        </form>

<div style="width: 100%;height:auto ; position:absolute; bottom:0;left:0;background-color: black; ">
    <a><img src="img/left_arrow.png" style="float: left ;padding:10px;height:50px"/><p style="text-align: left;line-height: 50px;font-size: 22px;color: #9d988d;font-weight: bolder">Back</p></a></div>
</div>              

</div>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

and my css code is:

```
 @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,300);
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 1000;
}
body {
  font-family: 'montserrat_alternatesregular';
  color: #DCDCDC;
  font-weight: 1000;

}
body ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  /* WebKit browsers */
  font-family: 'montserrat_alternatesregular';
  color: #DCDCDC;
  font-weight: 1000;
}
body :-moz-placeholder {
  /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
 font-family: 'montserrat_alternatesregular';
  color: #DCDCDC;
  opacity: 1;
  font-weight: 1000;
}
body ::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
  font-family: 'montserrat_alternatesregular';
  color: #DCDCDC;
  opacity: 1;
  font-weight: 1000;
}
body :-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
  font-family: 'montserrat_alternatesregular';
  color: #DCDCDC;
  font-weight: 1000;
}
a{

    text-decoration: none;
    color: white
}



.wrapper {

  left:0;
  top:0;
  background-size:100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
.wrapper.form-success .container h1 {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(85px);
      -ms-transform: translateY(85px);
          transform: translateY(85px);
}
.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background-size:cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-align: center;
}
.container h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
          transition-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-put;
          transition-timing-function: ease-in-put;
  font-weight: 150;
}
```

My actual screen[image]

After keyboard or inpspect elemnt is opened backround gets small and back button goes up[image]

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

> As you `css` layout is designed in percentages, once soft-keypad opens, container is re-sized hence content gets shrinked.

**Solution:**

On page load, set the height of `body` in pixels like this:

```
var bodyObj = $("body");
bodyObj.css('height', window.innerHeight + "px");
```

Comment: The issue is stiil tehere

Comment: Can you share the screenshot ? Just debug using `chrome://inspect` and check what value you are getting as `window.innerHeight`

Comment: see the background goes up and back button also when i open inspect element or virtual keyboard on mobile

Comment: For your information, It is a native behavior that when input is under focus, container will scroll to maintain `input` in view-point. `chrome://inspect` is a different thing, Not `inspect element`. Refer https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

From the html/css you have shared it seems that you have a background image for the "wrapper" div but you have added background properties for the "container" div. You should have the background properties set for the wrapper div instead to avoid the background image debacle.

But you can try by using position: relative instead for position: absolute

```
<div style="width: 100%;height:auto ; position:absolute; bottom:0;left:0;background-color: black; ">
    <a><img src="img/left_arrow.png" style="float: left ;padding:10px;height:50px"/><p style="text-align: left;line-height: 50px;font-size: 22px;color: #9d988d;font-weight: bolder">Back</p></a></div>
</div>
```